# Using Arrays within a Map

Tags: javascript

I'm rewriting an algorithm I originally wrote in C++, and looking for a similar implementation in JavaScript as what one would generally do in C++:

```
std::map<<std::string, std::vector<std::string>> my_map_of_vectors;
```

This is the closest I've got, but I'm struggling...

```
 var my_map = new Map();
 var array_history = [];

 // below within a for-loop...
 my_map.set(data_blob[row].s_col1,array_history.push({h_col1:data_blob[row].s_col2}));
```

And then to access the first element of the array, with a known key, I get nothing...

```
document.writeln(xer_map.get("GG1000").h_col1[0]);
```

Not sure where to go from here, any help is appreciated!

Comment: `push` does not return an array. It mutates the array and returns its new length. Not sure why you’re struggling — the [documentation](//developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push) is pretty clear on this.

Comment: Thanks. Unsure the backhanded comment was necessary.  Maybe because I've programmed in JavaScript all of 3 hours.